# Removing special character from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the data frame as below, I find special characters ''(,) inside it

when given df.head()

```
| SYSTEM_NAME | IP_ADDRESS      |
|-------------|-----------------|
| AAAA        | (xx.xx.xx.xx,) |
```

when viewed as dataframe inside IDE (pycharm)

```
| SYSTEM_NAME | IP_ADDRESS         |
|-------------|--------------------|
| AAAA        | ('xx.xx.xx.xx',)  |
```

My trials

```
df['IP_ADDRESS'] = df['IP_ADDRESS'].str[:-2]
this makes the column value '0'

df['IP_ADDRESS'] = df['IP_ADDRESS'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
this makes the column value 'nan'
```

I tried some other methods also to remove the special char

Required Output

```
| SYSTEM_NAME | IP_ADDRESS   |
|-------------|--------------|
| AAAA        | xx.xx.xx.xx |
```

Comment: Can you add some data to try with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a tuple to me, so give `.str[0]` a shot:

```
df['IP_ADDRESS'] = df['IP_ADDRESS'].str[0]
```